# Find $c$ such that $cy^3(1-y)^8$ for $0 \leq y \leq 1$ is a PDF

Tags: integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, beta-function

I have a function
$$f(y) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} cy^3(1-y)^8 & 0 \leq y \leq 1 \\
                                    0 & \text{ Otherwise.}\end{array}\right. .$$
I want to figure out what value of $c$ makes this function a legal probability
density function.

I'd imagine that we start out by setting
$$1 = \int_0^1 cy^3(1-y)^8 dy$$
$$\implies 1 = c \int_0^1 y^3(1-y)^8 dy.$$
However, the degrees seems to make this integral somewhat hard. I tried plugging
this into Wolfram, but I couldn't seem to get any meaningful information as to
how to calculate that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. One may recall the [Euler beta integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) (or [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.12)),
$$
\int_0^1 y^{a-1}(1-y)^{b-1} dy=\frac{\Gamma(a)\cdot \Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}
$$ giving
$$
\int_0^1 y^3(1-y)^8 dy=\frac{\Gamma(4)\cdot \Gamma(9)}{\Gamma(13)}=\frac{1}{1980}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can always expand $(1-y)^8$ with the binomial theorem and integrate term by term. Somewhat more elegant is to substitute $u=1-y$.